# For loop ends with its body

Tags: go

For loop ends with its body and dont go furter

I need find wIndex, check if its in the slice, if no add value
Where I go wrong?

```
var x make(map[int]float32, 10)
var s []int
var value = 100
for i := 1; i <= 10; i++ {
    wIndex := int(rand.Intn(len(x))) // random Index choice among map values
    for _, v := range s {            //end of loop here (if exactly it returnts to loop before)
        if v != wIndex {
            s = append(s, wIndex)
            x[wIndex] += value
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You start with an empty `s` slice. So you will never enter your inner for loop where you add elements to the slice.

Here is an alternative and straight forward way to do it:

```
for i := 1; i <= 10; i++ {
    wIndex := int(rand.Intn(len(x) + 1)) 
    found := false
    for _, v := range s {
        if v == wIndex {
            found = true
            break
        }
     }
     if !found {
        s = append(s, wIndex)
        x[wIndex] += float32(value)
     }
 }
```

- note that you need to convert the value to a float32, so `x[wIndex] += float32(value)` instead of just `x[wIndex] += value`
- `rand.Intn(n int)` generates numbers in the range [0,n), so you need to add 1 to cover the proper range, and avoid panic when the map is empty.

Comment: `if len(x) == 0`, it panics

Answer (score 0):

The inside loop will never execute because the slice does not have a value it is empty so insert a random value into the slice and then range over it.

There are other things to notice as well since `rand.Intn` already returns int then there is no need to type cast it into int.

```
int(rand.Intn(len(x))) // no requirement to typecast it into int.
```

One more thing is the length of map is `0` which is why the `rand.Intn` will throw an error when running your code.

```
wIndex := int(rand.Intn(len(x))) // This will throw an error.
```

Change your code as below.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math/rand"
)

func main() {

    var x = make(map[int]float32)
    var s []int
    var value = 100
    for i := 1; i <= 10; i++ {
        wIndex := rand.Intn(10) // random Index choice among map values
        s = append(s, wIndex)
        for _, v := range s { //end of loop here (if exactly it returnts to loop before)
            if v != wIndex {
                x[wIndex] += float32(value)
            }
        }
    }
    fmt.Println(s)
    fmt.Println(x)
}
```

Working Example on [Go playground](https://play.golang.org/p/0usp-5o1OfX)

Comment: @DenEmeryanov you can accept my answer if it helped.